# How to integrate Office 365 with Microsoft on-premise Multi-Factor Authentication?

Tags: azure, microsoft-office-365, adfs

We purchased Microsoft Multi-Factor Authentication (on-premise).  How do I integrate that with Office 365?

We have Azure AD Connect syncing on premise AD to Azure.  We also have ADFS setup to enable SSO for Office 365.  Do I just need to install the MFA server on the ADFS server and configure it like any other ADFS application?  We will be using the MFA server to secure some other applications as well which is why we are not using the included Office 365 MFA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, as you are using ADFS for your Office 365 logins you just need to configure ADFS to use the MFA server. Office is effectively handing over the authentication process to your ADFS setup.